# Push notification not working

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, push-notifications

the problem I am having is with Push notifications in Android. 
In order to receive my WhatsApp notifications I need to manually launch the application, which I don't want do. I want to be able to receive my notifications at any time...

I've heard that it might be due to the Push Notification not working so, I decided to download from Google Play the app `PNF No-Root` which changed the heartbeat interval to 5 minutes (I use WLAN connection) and it didn't work at all (the same for similar apps). I tried looking for other solutions. I went to `Settings > Data Usage > WLAN > WhatsApp` to check if the Restrict background data box was unchecked, it was unchecked.
I also went to `Apps > WhatsApp` to see if the box "Show Notifications" was Checked. Went to `WLAN > ADVANCED` and set "Keep WLAN on during sleep" as "Always". Finally, I launched WhatsApp and all the settings are correctly set for me to receive, but I don't. When I go to `Apps > Running > Whatsapp` it says that there is 1 Process and to Services (although it shows 1 service sometimes), `ExternalMediaManager` and `MessageService`.
My device is a `Lenovo A5000` with `Android OS 4.4.2`
 I don't know what else to try, thanks.

Comment: A possibility is mentioned here: [Apps constantly disconnecting from the internet](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/172665). Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any power save mode set?

Otherwise Download the app "Wifi settings" and change the DNS Server to Google and hit apply . I hope this will help

Comment: Please link the app in your answer and highlight the specific capability of the app that would help OP- this would enhance the value of your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have any **task killer** app installed in your device, uninstall it or keep the **WhatsApp** app in the ignore list of that task killer.